# Make jQuery mouseenter apply to new new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.class1').mouseenter(function() {

   $('<div class="class1"> </div>').appendTo('body');

});
```

The above is pseudo-ish code which shows what I'm trying to do. I mouse-over an element of class1, and another element of class1 is created.

My problem is that this `mouseenter` binder does not trigger for the new class1 elements that are created. How can I get this `mouseenter` trigger to apply to the newly created elements as well?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do mouse enter on element that doesn't exist!

Comment: So I need some way to 'reapply' this binding to all `class1` elements after the new one has been created.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Once you have created an element dynamically and appended to DOM then use jQuery's on method for event delegation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, you can bind events with 'on' so the event is delegated to contained elements matching a specified selector.

So in your case, bind the event to the body, and specify the `class1` selector, like this:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter' ,'.class1', function(e) {
    $('<div class="class1"></div>').appendTo('body');
});
```

See the docs here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

The function for versions < 1.7 to use to achieve this is 'live()', this was deprecated in version 1.7 in favour of the upgraded 'on()' method. See the old docs here for more information: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Cerbus, you have to append to proper root element in your fiddle script

Comment: Yes they do; you're appending the new <div> tags in that Fiddle to the body, but binding the event delegation to the #container element. If you append them to the #container, or bind the event to the body, it works as expected.

Comment: Examples of how to achieve this are all in the docs I linked to; if whoever downvoted my answer could remove it I'd appreciate it, my solution [works](http://jsfiddle.net/LVgDm/).

Answer (score 2):

The better solution would be to use .on() on the parent element or even the body instead.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.class1', function(){
     $(this).append('<div class="class1"> </div>');
});
```

This works more similarly to the old live() event, as the parent will look for the event on any new elements added to body as well.

EDIT: don't forget to use $(this) inside of that function instead of forcing jQuery to do a second DOM lookup :) sorry I noobed out on that one

Comment: @Derek: I know, I posted my comment when the answer still contained code like the fiddle I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `delegate` or `on` methods (depending on jquery version that you use).

Basically, you attach delegate on parent element and listen to actions on children.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.class1', function() {});
```

This registers event handler only on the `body` element.

Comment: Right, I'm using #container as target element. @JoeRocc wants to use body, which I overlooked. I updated my response.

Comment: @Derek: I know, I posted my comment when the answer still contained code like the fiddle I posted.

Answer (score 0):

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/DR2zz/2/):

```
$('body').mouseenter(addDiv);

function addDiv() {
    $('<div class="class1"> </div>').appendTo('body');
}
```

[Newly added divs don't trigger the function](http://jsfiddle.net/DR2zz/) when using `$('#container').on('mouseenter', '.class1', addDiv);`

Fixed the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DR2zz/2/) and code.

However, [Jed Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744579/jed-watson) made a [better suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626088/1835379)

Comment: That's impractical and not correct. You can delegate events to objects that aren't created yet - see my answer and fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LVgDm/)